# OnScrollListener свайп вниз

Tags: android, прокрутка, swipe

Как с помощью OnScrollListener организовать свайп вниз, чтобы все новые элементы подгружались сверху?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрошенная вами фича называется *Pull-To-Refresh*

В сети много реализаций этой фичи, [например](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pull+to+refresh&type=)

Comment: Не совсем, мне нужно что-то на подобии того, как это выглядит в чатах